# Are the Sam & Max Beyond Time and Space episodes based on real stories?

Tags: sam-and-max

Each episode of the 2008 video game *[Sam & Max Beyond Time and Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_%26_Max_Beyond_Time_and_Space)* has a title card saying that it is based on some obscure story.

[image: Sam & Max Freelance Police in: Ice Station Santa]

> **Ice Station Santa**
>
> Based on the obscure holiday penny dreadful "Sam & Max and the Case of the Frostbitten Protuberance"

[image: Sam & Max Freelance Police in: Moai Better Blues]

> **Moai Better Blues**
>
> Based on the unfinished teleplay "Sam & Max Jump in a Triangle"

There was an animated TV show entitled *[The Adventures of Sam & Max: Freelance Police](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Sam_%26_Max:_Freelance_Police)*, so it is plausible that it is based on the script for an unfinished episode.

[image: Sam & Max Freelance Police in: Night of the Raving Dead]

> **Night of the Raving Dead**
>
> Based on the heretical apocrypha "Sam & Max Meet a Guy Who Sucks"

[image: Sam & Max Freelance Police in: Chariots of the Dogs]

> **Chariots of the Dogs**
>
> Based on the best-selling addle-brained musings of aliens-made-all-our-stuff-theorist Erich von Dannyohday

[image: Sam & Max Freelance Police in: What's new, Beelzebub?]

> **What's new, Beelzebub?**
>
> Based on the heartwarming holiday sestina, "Sam & Max Meet the Father of Lies"

I'm finding it difficult to find information on the names of the stories from the original comic series, so I'm not sure if there were made up. Are any of these real Sam & Max stories?

Comment: I was pretty sure they weren't, but I'm not familiar enough with the originals.

Comment: These are all based on real stories / movies, just not from the comic series. "What's new, pussycat?" Chariots of the God's as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of these are stories from the *SAM & MAX* comic books. It's been a while but I have read those multiple times, and the stories don't match up. Similarly, I haven't seen all the stories from the animated series (the only one that sticks out was a trek through the Arctic tundra of their own freezer), but these don't logically match up with those either.

The actual episode names *are* based on movies (and/or books) (that have nothing to do with Sam and Max):

- [Ice Station Zebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Station_Zebra)
- [Mo' Better Blues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mo%27_Better_Blues)
- [Night of the Living Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Living_Dead)
- [Chariots of the Gods?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chariots_of_the_Gods%3F) (by Erich Von Daniken)
- [What's New Pussycat?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What%27s_New_Pussycat%3F)

The "based on the story" names are clearly intended to simply be another part of the joke. The names come from the game stories, whether directly (in "Moai Better Blues", they do jump through a triangle several times) od indirectly (no one gets frostbite in "Ice Station Santa", but hanging around outdoors at the North Pole certainly *could* lead to that), or on the original story (unless Erich von Dannyohday turns out to be a character in Chariot of the Dogs - I actually started the game last week, and have only finished the first two "chapters")

As an (irrelevant) aside: about the only reference to the original comics I can pick out is a picture from the Philippines in the office, where they went in their first story. As noted in that story (quoting from memory, fittingly enough):

> Sam: Well here we are in the Philippines!
>
> Max: Obviously drawn without any reference materials!

(Or something like that).

But, that's just an in-joke for long-time fans, not important to the stories themselves.

Comment: So you're saying that the subtitles aren't related to anything and are just original jokes, as far as we can tell? The only connection I can see right now is "Erich Von Daniken" being the "Erich von Dannyohday" in the fourth episode.

Comment: Updated w/ response; the joke subtitles are tied to the game stories, or in at least one case (Erich von Dannyohday) to the source the actual title was taken from..

Comment: After it finally occurred to me to look up the meaning of "sestina", I decided that the subtitles had to be jokes. Thanks for providing more substantial proof!